# Link styled as a button, printed as link without styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and when I create a styled link like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
```

When I want to print the page, the styled buttons are printed like a unstyled link.
Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When you print a webpage, the default (print.css) is used instead of user-defined CSS to ensure proper display on the page. Hence your class "btn btn-primary" is not considered.

You may include in your webpage a print.css where you can add your own styles

**NOTE:** If you do not provide a print.css, you see that the alignment, layout, colour and font are all in their non-styled form.

Comment: I know its a bit old school, but `@media print` css statements work just fine too. no additional css files necessary.

Answer (score 0):

print You should use special print styles and correct 'media" word

```
@media print {
    body {
     font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
     font-size: 0.9em;
     color: #000080;
   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `@media print` ?

Comment: Yes it will be @media print

Answer (score 0):

If you have `btn btn-primary` CSS defined in a stylesheet or media query block that specifies only SCREEN, then it would print without any styling.  However, if your original CSS is all-purpose, then you should see it print similarly to how it looks on screen.

Comment: I don't know what your setup is.  Can you make the site live and post the URL?